# mysql retrieve data from 3 tables

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables with user_id is common column in all 3 tables. I want only those rows from 3 tables which has `user_id = 4`.
For e.g.
I have 3 tables as below

1. table1 (user_id, user_name)
2. table2 (user_id, user_email)
3. table3 (user_id, user_password)

Now, I want rows from all 3 tables which has `user_id = 4`.

I have tried below query but not getting success:

```
SELECT t1.user_name,t2.user_email,t3.user_password 
FROM table1 as t1 
   LEFT JOIN table2 as t2 ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id 
   LEFT JOIN table3 as t3 ON t1.user_id = t3.user_id 
WHERE t1.user_id = '4'
```

Please let me know, how to get data

Comment: Describe `not getting success`. In the DB, in PHP? Error message? wrong results?

Comment: Your query looks correct for the data you describe and what you want to do.

Comment: in PHP with mysql DB. error is: I have total 12 rows from all 3 tables which has user_id = 4, but I got around 30 rows with above query.

Comment: PHP is not necessary here, I just run query in mysql and not getting desired result. I am using PHP to show all these data but question is I am not getting the result that I want.

I have 3 rows in table 1 which has user id = 4, 2 rows from table 2 which has user id = 4 and 1 row from table having user id = 4. So I want total (3+2+1=6) rows.

Comment: Then you need a UNION not JOIN. Please post sample data end expected result.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Seems you have the answer there...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you probably need is `UNION` and not `JOIN`

```sql
select 'user_name' as attribite, user_name as entry 
from table1 
where user_id = '4'
union all
select 'user_email' as attribite, user_email as entry 
from table2 
where user_id = '4'
union all
select 'user_password' as attribite, user_password as entry 
from table3 
where user_id = '4'
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/35bf17/3

If you use `JOIN` like you did, you will get all combinations of username, email and password for one user.

Comment: You made my day. This way I got the combination for one user.. Thanks very much :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you don't have that user_id = 4 on every table so thats why your query retries no data.

If you join the tables on two conditions you will retrieve it even if there is no data in one of the tables.

```
SELECT
    t1.user_name,
    t2.user_email,
    t3.user_password
FROM
    table1 AS t1
    LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2
        ON (
            t1.user_id = t2.user_id
            AND t2.user_id = 4
        )
    LEFT JOIN table3 AS t3
        ON (
            t1.user_id = t3.user_id
            AND t3.user_id = 4
        )
WHERE
    t1.user_id = 4
```

With this you will always get results if there is `user_id = 4` in `table1`. And null values for the rest of the tables.

Comment: IF he didnt have a `user_id` column on one of the tables, then the query would not compile! And neither would yours

Comment: Sorry, I meant that maybe he didn't have `user_id = 4`, not that he didn't have a column named `user_id`

Comment: I have same column in all tables with user_id and all table have rows in which user_id as 4 as value

Comment: See this comment from the OP http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38944520/mysql-retrive-data-from-3-tables#comment65244024_38944520 It might effect your answer.

Comment: This will return the exactly same result as the original query. The additinal conditions are redundant, because `t1.user_id` is allways `4`.